# Error while do ` ionic cordova build android` fro ionic 3

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, android-sdk-2.3

I am getting this error when i do `build for android` dont know what to do. I tried remove platform and add it again. But still getting same error. Should i need to remove my android sdk and install it again in my mac ?

**my error :**

```
✖ Running command - failed!

[ERROR] Cordova encountered an error.
        You may get more insight by running the Cordova command above directly.

[ERROR] An error occurred while running cordova build android (exit code 1):

        ANDROID_HOME=/Users/apple/Library/Android/sdk
        JAVA_HOME=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_121.jdk/Contents/Home

        FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

        * What went wrong:
        Failed to load native library 'libnative-platform.dylib' for Mac OS X x86_64.

        * Try:
        Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
        Error: /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/gradle/gradle-2.14.1/bin/gradle: Command failed with exit code 1
```

Comment: did you got any solution to this error @hybrid Dev

Comment: @Mohan Gopi  things i tried: 1. I created new project and copied the www folder and again i did " sudo ionic cordova build android". this time its works fine

Comment: @MohanGopi  if you again got this error : do `npm install -g ionic@latest`
`$ npm install --save-dev --save-exact @ionic/cli-plugin-ionic1@latest @ionic/cli-plugin-cordova@latest`  And then do " suod ionic cordova build android`

Answer (score 0):

I am also facing same issue .. but it work fine with me when make command

```
$ ionic cordova build android  --stacktrace
```

Comment: WHAT IS THAT CODE MEANS  :  `ionic cordova build android  --stacktrace`   ` stacktrace` is what to measn whil we build