# Running command - failed! & Error: spawn EACCES

Tags: android, cordova, sdk, ionic2, ionic3

I am working on mac please take a look at my [image: error]

here is my **~/.bash-profile**

```
export PATH=$PATH:/Users/xxxxx/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools/
export ANDROID_HOME=/Users/xxxx/Library/Android/sdk/
export PATH=$ANDROID_HOME/platform-tools:$PATH
export PATH=$ANDROID_HOME/tools:$PATH
even $(user/libexec/path_helper -s)
```

and my **ionic info** result is

```
global packages:

    @ionic/cli-utils : 1.1.2
    Cordova CLI      : 7.0.1 
    Ionic CLI        : 3.1.2

local packages:

    @ionic/app-scripts              : 1.3.7
    @ionic/cli-plugin-cordova       : 1.1.2
    @ionic/cli-plugin-ionic-angular : 1.1.2
    Ionic Framework                 : ionic-angular 3.2.1

System:

    Node       : v6.10.0
    OS         : OS X El Capitan
    Xcode      : Xcode 8.2.1 Build version 8C1002 
    ios-deploy : not installed
    ios-sim    : not installed
```

> on giving ionic cordova build android i am getting the above image error
>
> i belive it is something to deal with the environmental variable what i am missing is there anything i have to specify for mac.
>
> the above same environment is working in my linux system.

Comment: maybe it is a folder access issue? did you try with sudo maybe

Comment: imported project from windows to mac? if yes..remove and add platform again

Comment: @suraj i tried `sudo ionic cordova build android` and `ionic cordova build android` both gives me the above error

Comment: @varunaaruru no i have not done anything i just created the project and added my platform in mac only \

Comment: what is the output for `cordova requirements` ?

Comment: @suraj i too do't know what is the cordova requirement all i did is created an new project and added platform and then i tried to build it then i am facing this issues i have  not installed anything in cordova

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43916498/error-while-do-ionic-cordova-build-android-fro-ionic-3 this might help

Comment: i tried that one it is not working @varunaaruru

Comment: @MohanGopi its a command.. it will check if all requirements for cordova build commands are met

Comment: @suraj everthing like android sdk, javajdk, android target, greadle somethings like that i am getting printed i mean the information about this is shown for the command `cordova requirements`

Answer (score 0):

I also faced this frustrating issue when upgrading from 2 -> 3.  It turned out to be a permission where cordova was installed.

Run:
`which cordova // this gave me /usr/local/bin/cordova`

Then I had to change the owner of that file.

Run: 
`chmod -r 777 /usr/local/bin/cordova`

Not sure why, but for some reason even when I ran the Ionic commands under `sudo`, i still got a permission error.